# Incorrect Parsing of simple arithmetic grammar in ANTLR

Tags: parsing, antlr

I recently started studying ANTLR. Below is the grammar for the arithmetic expression.
The problem is that when I am putting (calling) expression rule in the `term` rule then it is parsing incorrectly even for (9+8). It is somehow ignoring the right parenthesis.

While when I put `add` rule instead of calling expression rule from the rule term, it is working fine.

As in:

```
term:
INTEGER
| '(' add ')'
;
```

Can anyone tell me why it is happening because more or les they both are the same.

Grammer for which it is giving incorrect results

```
term
  :
  INTEGER
  | '(' expression ')'
  ;

mult
  :
  term ('*' term)*
  ;

add
  :
  mult ('+' mult)*
  ;

expression
  :
  add
  ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I parse `"(8+9)"` with a parser generated from your grammar, starting with the `expression` rule, I get the following parse tree:

[image]

In other words: it works just fine.

Perhaps you're using ANTLRWorks' (or ANTLR IDE's) interpreter to test your grammar? In thta case: don't use the interpreter, it's buggy. Use ANTLRWorks' debugger instead (the image is exported from ANTLRWorks' debugger).

Comment: Thanks Bart now I can finally move on from it :D , and FYI I am using eclipse IDE along with antlr.

Comment: Bart's answer is perfect.  Watch for ANTLRworks 2 ... in development and appears to be a complete rewrite so hopefully we will see better results in the future.